# openapi-generatorで生成されたrustのコードでエラーがでる。

Tags: rust, openapi-generator, openapi

openapi-generatorで以下のコードが生成されたのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

```
/*
 * EPGStation
 *
 * No description provided (generated by Openapi Generator https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator)
 *
 * The version of the OpenAPI document: 1.5.4
 * 
 * Generated by: https://openapi-generator.tech
 */


#[allow(unused_imports)]
use serde_json::Value;


#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct RecordedDeletes {
    #[serde(rename = "recordedIds")]
    pub recorded_ids: Vec<i32>,
    /// onlyTs: TS だけ削除, onlyEncoded: エンコード済みファイル削除のみ削除
    #[serde(rename = "option", skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub option: Option<String>,
}

impl RecordedDeletes {
    pub fn new(recorded_ids: Vec<i32>) -> RecordedDeletes {
        RecordedDeletes {
            recorded_ids: recorded_ids,
            option: None,
        }
    }
}

/// onlyTs: TS だけ削除, onlyEncoded: エンコード済みファイル削除のみ削除
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum Option {
    #[serde(rename = "onlyTs")]
    OnlyTs,
    #[serde(rename = "onlyEncoded")]
    OnlyEncoded,
}
```

エラー1

```
warning: unused import: `super::models::*`
  --> generated/src/apis/mod.rs:52:5
   |
52 | use super::models::*;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default

warning: unused import: `std::collections::HashMap`
  --> generated/src/apis/configuration.rs:12:5
   |
12 | use std::collections::HashMap;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 0, found 1
  --> generated/src/models/recorded_deletes.rs:22:24
   |
22 |     pub option: Option<String>,
   |                        ^^^^^^ unexpected type argument

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0107`.
error: Could not compile `openapi`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

`<String>`を消してみましたが次に以下のエラーが出るようになってしまいました。

エラー2

```
warning: unused import: `super::models::*`
  --> generated/src/apis/mod.rs:52:5
   |
52 | use super::models::*;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default

warning: unused import: `std::collections::HashMap`
  --> generated/src/apis/configuration.rs:12:5
   |
12 | use std::collections::HashMap;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: unreachable expression
   --> generated/src/apis/recorded_api.rs:172:9
    |
172 | /         __internal_request::Request::new(hyper::Method::Post, "/recorded/{id}/upload".to_string())
173 | |             .with_path_param("id".to_string(), id.to_string())
174 | |             .with_form_param("directory".to_string(), directory.to_string())
175 | |             .with_form_param("encoded".to_string(), encoded.to_string())
176 | |             .with_form_param("name".to_string(), name.to_string())
177 | |             .with_form_param("file".to_string(), unimplemented!())
    | |__________________________________________________________________^
    |
    = note: #[warn(unreachable_code)] on by default

error[E0599]: no variant or associated item named `is_none` found for type `models::recorded_deletes::Option` in the current scope
  --> generated/src/models/recorded_deletes.rs:21:54
   |
21 |     #[serde(rename = "option", skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ variant or associated item not found in `models::recorded_deletes::Option`
...
36 | pub enum Option {
   | --------------- variant or associated item `is_none` not found here

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> generated/src/models/recorded_deletes.rs:29:21
   |
29 |             option: None,
   |                     ^^^^ expected enum `models::recorded_deletes::Option`, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `models::recorded_deletes::Option`
              found type `std::option::Option<_>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0308, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: Could not compile `openapi`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

解決法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAPIスキーマ側で定義されている `Option` というモデルが、Rust標準ライブラリの `Option` 型と衝突しているせいで想定どおりの挙動をしていないのだと思われます。解決方法として以下が考えられます。

1. スキーマファイルに手を加えて、 `Option` 以外の名前を使用する。
2. ジェネレーターに手を加えて、当該モデルを別の型名として生成できるようにする。
3. ジェネレーターに手を加えて、Rust標準ライブラリの `Option` を指している箇所を `::std::option::Option` という完全修飾名で参照するようにする。

1は確実ですがAPI定義に手を加えることになります。2と3はジェネレーター側の対応状況次第ですが、openapi-generatorでそれができるのかどうかは少し調べた範囲ではわかりませんでした。

Comment: 回答がりがとうございます。1の方法でやってみます。